# Using intersect with split

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I have this data in text files

**file1.txt**

```
111|test1

222|test2

333|test3
```

**file2.txt**

```
111|test4

444|test5

555|test6
```

The `"output.text"` at the end will contain

```
111|test1
```

So basically ignore the data after the pipe but at the end preserve that data.
How can I do this in `vb.net` or `c#`?

Comment: you want pipes in the output? Where did the aaa and bbb come from? Can you elaborate a little more?

Comment: basically to preserve the data after pipe but ignore it while doing the intersect

Comment: Odd. You asked the same question at expert exchange and I think it has been answered. http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/.NET/Visual_Basic.NET/Q_28222278.html

Comment: @Farax its not odd I am always looking for better ways to improve my code..

Comment: You have to refer to the original reference ...

Comment: @user177352 im not using someone else's question.. its my own question therefore I have full copyright to it and I don't have to reference it.

Comment: Will blank lines be present in the text files, between the lines with data? Can a line have more than one pipe char `|` in it. Will it always be numbers in the front of each line? What do the numbers mean? Are they guaranteed to be sorted in the text file, and is the output file required to be sorted as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [String.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx)

**N:B:** Returns a string array that contains the substrings in this instance that are delimited by elements of a specified string or Unicode character array.

Comment: He wants to ignore the stuff after the pipe during the intersect. How would he use String.split there?

Comment: you can first read the 2 file individually and split it and keep it in 2 array of string in a sorted manner. then compare the 2 array and finally save the compared output to another file. @Farax

Comment: This could be a comment instead of an answer.

Comment: Yes, so you should add the detail to your answer too. It is not clear what you wanted him to do using string.split

Comment: @Farax OP can build the logic in many way if he get the clue of what is actually the raw material he need to build the logic.